# How should I handle Filter and Futures in play2 and Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to learn Futures and ReactiveMongo.
In my case I have a couple of invite objects and want to filter out the ones that already exist in the db. I do not want to update or upsert the ones already in the db. Therefore I have created a filter method:

**filter method:**

```
def isAllowedToReview(invite: Invite): Future[Boolean] = {
    ReviewDAO.findById(invite.recoId, invite.invitedUserId).map {
      maybeReview => {
        maybeReview match {
          case Some(review) => false
          case None => true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**DAO:**

```
def findById(rId: Long, userId: Long): Future[Option[Review]] = findOne(Json.obj("rId" -> recoId, "userId" -> userId))

def findOne(query: JsObject)(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[Option[T]] = {    
   collection.find(query).one[T]
}
```

and then call:

```
val futureOptionSet: Set[Future[Option[Invite]]] = smsSet.filter(isAllowedToReview)
save the filtered set somehow...
```

this doesn't work since filter expects in this case `Invite => Boolean` but I'm sending `Invite => Future(Boolean)`. How would you filter and save this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smsSet.map(sms => isAllowedToReview(sms).map(b => sms -> b))` will have type `Set[Future[(Invite, Boolean)]]`. You should be able to call `Future.sequence` to turn it into a `Future[Set[(Invite, Boolean)]]`. Then you can collect the results `.map(_.collect{ case (sms, true) => sms})`.

So putting everything together a solution may look like this:

```
val futures = smsSet.map(sms => isAllowedToReview(sms).map(b => sms -> b))
val future = Future.sequence(futures)
val result = future.map(_.collect{ case (sms, true) => sms})
```

When you see `map` and `sequence` you may be able to refactor to:

```
val filteredSet = Future.traverse(smsSet){ sms => 
  isAllowedToReview(sms).map(b => sms -> b)
}.map(_.collect{ case (sms, true) => sms})
```

Note that instead of returning the set, you may just want to save your sms there. But the way I wrote this, all will be wrapped in a `Future` and you can still compose with other operations.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I understand how I should work with the filteredSet. Let say I would like to call the insert method on the sms which returns Future[Option[Invite]]. This will make the code return Future[Set[Future[Option[Invite]]]] which I guess i should flatten somehow? Or maybe i should return sms as in your example and then work with filteredSet.map() ? how would you do it?

Comment: Would: val futureInserted : Future[Set[Option[Invite]]] = filteredSet.flatMap {
              invites => Future.traverse(invites)(insertReview)
            } be a nice way of traversing futureInserted?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
val revsFut = Future.sequence(smsSet.map(invite => ReviewDAO.findById(invite.recoId, invite.invitedUserId)))    
val toSave = for(revs <- revsFut) yield {
  val flatRevs = revs.flatten
  smsSet.filter{ invite =>
    flatRevs.find(review => /*Add filter code here */).isDefined
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is first fetching the Set of reviews matching the the invites by mapping over the smsSet, fetching each individually and then sequencing that into one singe `Future`.  Then, in the for-comprehension I flatten the `Set` of `Option[Review]` and then filter down the `smsSet` based on what's in that `flatRevs` Set.  Since I don't know your object model, I had to leave the impl of the `flatRevs.find` up to you, but it should be pretty easy as that point.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! Could you help me to understand how I should work with toSave. Let say I would like to perform an insert operation on toSave and call insert that receives an Invite saves it and everything goes well it returns Future[Option[Invite]]. So let say I would like to have a Future[Set[Option[Invite]]] at the end how should i compose the method? Maybe I'm thinking wrong?